# Postgresql ODBC driver configuration

Tags: networking, odbc

I am trying to connect postgresql server which is running on Linux machine from Windows 7. I have installed windows 64 bit ODBC drivers for postgresql and I changed pg_hba.conf file under IPV4 as 0.0.0.0.0/0 to accept connection from any host. Also, I did make sure that my server is listening on 5432 port to which I am trying to connect. Still I am facing connection failure error. Error is -

> "Could not connect to server; A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period...

Comment: Easiest way to check.  Run the following from the command prompt: `telnet <hostname> 5432`.  If you get a connection your physical connectivity is fine.

Comment: I did telnet and its not connecting, regarding the firewalls - I tried verifying iptables in fedora(my server) but could not do significant. Any suggestions, am I missing anything related to config files here?

Comment: I have tried changing postgresql.conf the list_addresses to * (to accept from any clinet) and also started postgres with -i option. But, neither of them worked.